# How to auto-adjust container width when image inside is resized?

Tags: css

I'm having an issue, which I will simplify here for sake of clarity (its really frustrating me).

I have a container with two divs in it (and one has an image inside, which will be resized), like so:

HTML

```
<div id="container">

<div id="block1">

    <img src="images/clank.png">

</div>

<div id="block2">

</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
height:350px;
background-color: #000

}

img {

max-width: 60%;
height: auto;

}

#block1 {
background-color: #fff;
float:left;
height:auto;
width: auto;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #000;
}

#block2 {
background-color: #456545; 
height:100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Here is an image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWPs6.png)

The image above illustrates my problem. After resizing the image inside #block1, the height of #block1 reduces, to be the same new height as the image (which is what I want). However, I want the width to do this as well, which doesn't happen. The width stays the same, so the width of #block1 does not change to be equal to the new size of the image (it stays the size of the original image).  I want the width of #block1 to automatically reduce in accordance with the new smaller size of the image.

Is this possible via CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

In the event that you do not want your `img` element to occupy the full dimensions of the containing `div`, you can have the `img` element scaled by a percentage of the container for both height and width by setting the percentage for the `padding` property. See below for what I mean.

*Old:*

*You can't have `max-width` set at `60%` for the `img` and expect to have the width of the container match that of the `img`. See below when I have removed the `max-width` restriction:*

```css
*, :before, :after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #000
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 50% 50% 0;
}

#block1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 20%; /* change this to see that the div fits the image properly. */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #000;
}

#block2 {
  background-color: #456545;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="block1">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97300&w=200&h=300">
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still having the same issue though. If you reduce the img height and width to 50% both in your code above, for example, the issue from the picture I posted still continues. The height scales but the width does not reduce. Unless I'm doing something wrong..

img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

Comment: If you want to match the container's dimensions with that of the image, change the container dimensions and not the image dimensions.

Comment: Awesome, it worked!! Thanks for all the help, wish I could give 100 upvotes lol

Comment: You're welcome! I'll take the one you can give, though. :)